# Modify or delete data of some tables while taking backup of sql server database but without affecting on original database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete/Modify the data from some of the tables while taking a backup of the connected SQL server database. But don't want to reflect this change on the connected database.

Please give me the idea to achieve my task.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want to change the data in the database but don't want it reflected in the database? That conflicts. Please take the time to elaborate on your actual problem.

Comment: Create a database snapshot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16, make changes, take backup then revert to the snapshot. If you want to keep the DB active while you do this then you need to clone it instead.